# Is there any way creating dynamic @ServerEndpoint address in Java?

Tags: java, websocket, server, endpoint

For example, I have a  room

```
public class Room {
   private int id;
   private Set<User> users;
}
```

So I want it to be endpoint for my websocket application. But there may be a lot of rooms and I want each of them could have own URI (for example, rooms/1, rooms/2 etc.)

Evidently, @ServerEnpoint annotaion allows only constants. So, is there any way to make it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/rooms/{roomnumber}")
public class....

static Map<String, Session> openSessions = ...
@OnOpen
public void onConnectionOpen(final Session session, @PathParam("roomnumber") final String roomnumber, 
...
   //store roomnumber in session
   session.getUserProperties().put("roomnumber", roomnumber);
   openSessions.put( String.valueOf(session.getId()), session )
```

To only send messages to specific roomnumbers/clients:

```
// check if session corresponds to the roomnumber 
  for (Map.Entry<String, Session> entry : openSessions.entrySet()) {

    Session s = entry.getValue();
    if (s.isOpen() && s.getUserProperties().get("roomnumber").equals(roomnumber_you_want_to_address)) {
  ...
```

And when a client disconnects:

```
 @OnClose
public void onConnectionClose(Session session) {
    openSessions.remove(session.getId());
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure it's the thing I need
I mean i have to associate endpoint with instance at runtime. For example, I create new instance of Room and it maps to necessary address. 
I alse need server to send message only to those clients who lconnected to this URI.
If I make it like you offered, I cant really imagine how can I make it

Answer (score -2):

You can use this per function to map requests with different variables in the same controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint/{endpointVariable}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ReturnDTO getReturnDTO(<params>){
    // Here the variable, endpointVariable, will be accessible
    // In my experiences its always been an integer, but I'm sure a string
    // would be possible.  check with debugger
}
```

http://www.journaldev.com/3358/spring-mvc-requestmapping-annotation-example-with-controller-methods-headers-params-requestparam-pathvariable

Comment: The question is about WebSocket and not Spring MVC! `@ServerEndpoint`is an annotation of `javax.websocket.server` package.

Comment: True...  I provided something that didn't quite answer the question.